# Changing color of text depending on user selection with PHP, CSS and HTML

Tags: php, html, css

My assignment asks me to make a select list of colors and then use PHP to print a statement in the color selected.  Here's exactly what it said:

1. Make an HTML form with a select-option list with the following color options:
   Red, Blue, and Green.

   When the user makes a selection and clicks the submit button display the
   following line in whatever color they selected. If they choose red, for example,
   it would look like...

   Color me happy

Use a CSS class to set the color of the text.

**THIS IS WHAT HE SAID TO DO:**

**HTML**

```
    <p>
    <select name="colorchoice" size="1">
    <option value="redtext">Red</option>
    <option value="bluetext">Blue</option>
    <option value="greentext">Green</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Information">
    </p>
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php
    $colorvalue = $_POST['colorchoice'];
    print "<span class='".$colorvalue."'> Color me happy.</span>";
    ?>
```

Obviously, this doesn't work without some CSS, which he so helpfully didn't mention.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Javascript or jquery?

Comment: No, only HTML, PHP and CSS.  I found a js solution on here.

Comment: add this in your CSS -> `.redtext{color:red;} .bluetext{color:blue;} .greentext{color:green;}`

Comment: Change the $_POST to $_GET, because by default a form submits its data with the GET-method, if you missed it - i can't see any form wrapper

Comment: The added classes were my first step.  Just changed post to get in both the HTML and PHP.  We have not covered get in class yet lol.  There is a form wrapper, I just didn't include it.  Still not working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping everything as simple as possible for your sake

```
<style>
    .red   { color: red; }
    .green { color: green; }
    .blue  { color: blue; }
</style>

<form>
    <select name="color">
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Color me!">
</form>

<?php
    if ( isset($_GET['color']) ) {
        print '<span class="' . $_GET['color'] . '">Color me happy.</span>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on the difference between $_POST and $_GET?  Get has not even been mentioned in class yet...

Answer (score 1):

myform.html:

```
<form action="ColorMe.php" method="post">
<select name="color">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Set Color"/>
</form>
```

ColorMe.php:

```
<?php
//Session is started for a PHP cookie to be resumed/created:
session_start();

//Gets the color from the form:
$Color = $_POST['color'];

//Sets the color to the PHP session UserColor:
$_SESSION['UserColor'] = $Color;

//Redirects to whatever page you want
header("Location: /MyPage.php");
```

MyPage.php:

```
<?php 
//Starts the session again to make the PHP session resources available:
session_start();

//Checks if the PHP session variable has been set:
if(isset($_SESSION['UserColor'])){

//If it is set: make $Color be whatever user selected:
$Color = $_SESSION['UserColor'];

}

//Otherwise, if not set:
else{

//Default color will be black:
$Color = "black";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Colored Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="color: <?php echo $Color; ?>;">Colored Text</h1>
<p style="color:<?php echo $Color; ?>;">Colored paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this what you wanted? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are new in PHP and HTML so i will give you very simple solution without dificulty , just for now and i wish you all the best

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['colorchoice'])) {
$colorvalue =$_POST['colorchoice'];      
print "<span ><font color=".$colorvalue.">Color me happy.</font></span>";
      }else{}    ?>
<form action="#" method=post>

<p> <select  name="colorchoice" size="1">
<option value="redtext">Red</option>
<option value="bluetext">Blue</option>
<option value="greentext">Green</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Information"></form>
</p>
```

**NOTE:**

when you start codding make sure that you open tag the close it , at your code you forgot to open form tag , so be carefull

Answer (score 1):

color.html file code:

```
<form action=color.php method=post
<select name="colorchoice">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option
<option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

color.php file code:

```
<?php
$colorvalue=$_POST['colorchoice'];
echo "<span style='color:". $colorvalue."'>Color me happy.</span>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<?php $colorvalue = $_POST['colorchoice'];
if($colorvalue == 'red'){?>
   <span style="color:red"> Red text </span>
 <?php } ?>
 if($colorvalue == 'green'){?>
   <span style="color:green"> green text </span>
 <?php } ?>
```

Obviously you can add individual class for each color instead of inline css. And make other conditions according to your desire